# Curl on Openshift console showing as "Empty reply from server"

Tags: kubernetes, containers, openshift, kubernetes-ingress, openshift-client-tools

The console pods are running but still not able to open the console.
Kindly let me know what is missing.

```
[root@api ~]# oc get nodes
NAME                   STATUS   ROLES           AGE     VERSION
ocp-cp-1.lab.ocp.lan   Ready    master,worker   4h59m   v1.18.3+002a51f
ocp-cp-2.lab.ocp.lan   Ready    master,worker   4h54m   v1.18.3+002a51f
ocp-cp-3.lab.ocp.lan   Ready    master,worker   4h48m   v1.18.3+002a51f
[root@api ~]#
[root@api ~]#

[root@api ~]#  oc get route -n openshift-console
NAME        HOST/PORT                                      PATH   SERVICES    PORT    TERMINATION          WILDCARD
console     console-openshift-console.apps.lab.ocp.lan            console     https   reencrypt/Redirect   None
downloads   downloads-openshift-console.apps.lab.ocp.lan          downloads   http    edge/Redirect        None
[root@api ~]#

[root@api ~]#  oc get pods -n openshift-ingress -owide
NAME                              READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE     IP               NODE                   NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
router-default-6c5f9d657b-bszbl   1/1     Running   0          4h43m   192.168.22.203   ocp-cp-3.lab.ocp.lan   <none>           <none>
router-default-6c5f9d657b-cznfx   1/1     Running   0          4h43m   192.168.22.202   ocp-cp-2.lab.ocp.lan   <none>           <none>
[root@api ~]#
```

When I do the curl, I am getting below error:

```
[root@api ~]# curl -L -k console-openshift-console.apps.lab.ocp.lan curl: (52) Empty reply from server [root@api ~]#
```

Comment: According to your console log, The console is waiting on the protocol https. I think you need to specify protocol "https" at first like "https://console-openshift-console.apps.....".

Comment: When I open `https://console-openshift-console.apps.lab.ocp.lan/` I get an error `This site can’t be reached`

Comment: What Load Balancer do you use in front of Ingress Controller (Router)? Does it work well?